# If map or filter is used inside another function, does that function become higher order?

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

If I use map or filter inside another function, does that function become a higher-order function? For example:

```
removeSpaces :: String -> String 
removeSpaces xs = filter (not . isSpace) xs
```

Is `removeSpaces` a higher-order function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `removeSpaces` is not a higher-order function.

A higher-order function is one that takes a function as an argument. `removeSpaces` doesn't, so it isn't.

Higher-orderness is a property of a function's interface, not its implementation, so we can tell that `removeSpaces` isn't higher-order just by looking at its type: it doesn't take any functions as arguments, so it's not higher-order. It is *implemented* with the use of a higher-order function, but that's another matter entirely.

For example, `filter` is a higher-order function, because it is declared as taking a function as a parameter:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

But `concat` isn't, because there aren't any function types (`a -> b`) as arguments:

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
```

Polymorphism poses a tricky edge-case: you can pass a function to `id` — `id concat [[1, 2], [3, 4]]` is `[1, 2, 3, 4]` — but its type does not declare it as taking any functions as arguments:

```
id :: a -> a
```

In this case, `id` is *not* higher-order. A function must explicitly have a function argument in its type to be higher-order.

Comment: yeah I clicked the tick few times. Apparently I have to wait 3 minutes to accept it. Finally accepted.. :)

Comment: @Gihan You can accept an answer after your question is 15 minutes old, not before that.

Comment: I wonder whether `(.)` from `Control.Category` can be called higher-order.

Comment: @Rotsor: No; similarly, `(+)` isn't higher-order, even though you can make functions an instance of `Num`. Certain instances (e.g. `instance Category (->)`) *do* have a higher-order `(.)`, but that's a property of the definitions in those instances, rather than `(.)` itself.

Comment: I think you'd probably also consider a function higher-order if it returns a function.

Answer (score 3):

No. A higher-order function is a function that takes another function as a parameter.

Rule of thumb: if the type signature contains an arrow in parens, and those parens aren't at the end of the type signature, like this: `(... -> ...) -> ...`, *then* the function is higher-order.

Answer (score 0):

nope, a higher order function use function as argument as `map` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, and not in your example.

A higher order function is a function that either takes a function as a parameter or returns a function as a result.

Your `removeSpaces` function does neither.

Comment: A function that returns another function as the result is not higher-order. Any 2-parameter function has that property.

Comment: @dflemstr: I believe definitions vary.  Not that wikipedia is authoritative, but this is the definition given there, and I think I've seen it in other places.  Currying of course can make more things look like higher order by this definition.